How to access DateTime index when running apply() on a pandas DataFrame?
I have two pandas DataFrames, daily_data contains daily close price data for a stock and weekly_data contains weekly close price data.
daily_data:
                               close
Date
2022-05-02 00:00:00-04:00  30.389999
2022-05-03 00:00:00-04:00  29.469999
2022-05-04 00:00:00-04:00  28.100000
2022-05-05 00:00:00-04:00  26.830000
2022-05-06 00:00:00-04:00  26.070000
2022-05-09 00:00:00-04:00  23.049999
2022-05-10 00:00:00-04:00  23.670000
2022-05-11 00:00:00-04:00  22.570000
2022-05-12 00:00:00-04:00  23.290001
2022-05-13 00:00:00-04:00  24.389999
2022-05-16 00:00:00-04:00  23.590000
...

weekly_data:
                               close
Date
2022-05-02 00:00:00-04:00  26.070000
2022-05-09 00:00:00-04:00  24.389999
2022-05-16 00:00:00-04:00  23.350000
2022-05-23 00:00:00-04:00  23.670000
2022-05-30 00:00:00-04:00  24.150000
2022-06-06 00:00:00-04:00  23.719999
...

I'm running apply(func1) on the daily DataFrame.
In func1() I need to get the iloc index of the week that the current day belongs to:
import pandas as pd

def func1(x)
    weekly_index = data_weekly.index.get_indexer([pd.to_datetime(x.index)], method='pad')
    return weekly_index[0]

daily_data['weekly_index'] = daily_data.apply(func1)

When running this code I get an "unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'" error.
However if I just run the following code outside of func1() it works:
index = weekly_data.index.get_indexer([pandas.to_datetime('2022-05-23 00:00:00-04:00')], method='pad')

Any insights on how to make this work in apply() would be much appreciated.

You're passing a string in one instance and a pd.Series (with pd.DataFrame.apply) in another. These are not the same type of object.

IIUC you can do:
def func1(x):
    weekly_index = weekly_data.index.get_indexer(x.index, method="pad")
    return weekly_index

daily_data["weekly_index"] = daily_data.apply(func1)
print(daily_data)

Prints:
                               close  weekly_index
Date                                              
2022-05-02 00:00:00-04:00  30.389999             0
2022-05-03 00:00:00-04:00  29.469999             0
2022-05-04 00:00:00-04:00  28.100000             0
2022-05-05 00:00:00-04:00  26.830000             0
2022-05-06 00:00:00-04:00  26.070000             0
2022-05-09 00:00:00-04:00  23.049999             1
2022-05-10 00:00:00-04:00  23.670000             1
2022-05-11 00:00:00-04:00  22.570000             1
2022-05-12 00:00:00-04:00  23.290001             1
2022-05-13 00:00:00-04:00  24.389999             1
2022-05-16 00:00:00-04:00  23.590000             2


I don't know how I missed that, thanks a lot!
